# PHP function on close with jQuery AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, postgresql

I've been working this problem for awhile and seen a lot of different approaches.  I have code that I believe should be working, but for one reason or another is not.

Here is my JavaScript code file name - test.js:

```
function deleteTempTable() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "exit.php",
        success: function(data) {
            alert("Deleting Temp Table");
        }
    });
}
```

I placed the alert purely for testing purposes to make sure the AJAX call was being made, and it is.

Here is the HTML for the button that makes the AJAX call file name - form.template:

```
<input type="button" title="Click to close window" value="Close" 
 onclick="deleteTempTable();" style="width:80px" name="close">
```

This does work as I get the JavaScript alert just fine.

Here is an EXAMPLE of the php code I'm using (it's not exact as it has some stuff I can't share, custom classes etc, either way I've reused this same pattern else where and it works fine and drops the tables as needed) file name - exit.php :

```
<?php
session_start();

require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "path/to/file.php";

$tempTableName = $_SESSION['tempTableName'];

//Not really hard coding this it's just an example
$odbcConn = odbc_connect('DataBaseName', 'UserName', 'Password'); 

$sqlCmd = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $tempTableName;";

odbc_exec($odbcConn, $sqlCmd);
?>
```

When I click the button the JavaScript alert pops up, but it appears as the the php is ignored since the table still exists.  Elsewhere in my code use the same php pattern to drop tables when new sets of data are requested, and they drop fine.  Just not when I try to do it with this button.

Any ideas or pointers would be great!

Also I saw this question, ["Calling PHP function using JQuery .ajax()"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320935/calling-php-function-using-jquery-ajax), but his problem was syntax, and I'm pretty sure with my IDE I'm not having a syntax error, and from what I've seen this is the solution posted.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to some suggestions I was able to get a test that would confirm the php code itself works, but is not actually being executed by the AJAX call.  Essentially I just ran the page that created the table, ie index.php, and then directed the browser to exit.php and the table was deleted as I would have expected.  So the only conclusion is that exit.php is not actually being called/executed by the AJAX call.

I don't know if this could be the problem but here is my actual url assignment (more or less): `url: "/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/exit.php"` I had tried `url: "exit.php"` as well, so I don't know if I need the full root path to the file or not, or if this is some how the issue.  At this point I'm just brain storming since I at least now know the php is not being executed or opened properly.

**UPDATE**

Well thanks to Salivador walking me through some trouble shooting the problem is solved.  Basically the code is correct.  So feel free to use it if you need to do something like this, however don't do what I did and mess up the PATH TO THE FILE!

*face palm*

Comment: I would start with showing all errors in your php file ( `ini_set('display_errors',1);` ) and do a `console.log(data);` in your success callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ajax call is executed, but are you sure that your PHP code is executed correctly and as intended?

Try to output the `$tempTableName` to see do you actually getting the right name for your table, try to see the response of `odbc_exec(...)` command to see what is the result of deletion.

Comment: That kind of what my concern was.  My primary "page" is comprised of an html templated form and an iframe "report".  I had tried to think of a creative way to test the php to ensure it was be executed at all, but a simple `echo` wasn't an option.  Though perhaps I can template an html script to do another javascript alert with `tempTableName`.  I'll give that shot too.

Comment: Ok so my php is not being called or ran.  Overall I'm fairly new to PHP, my background is in C++, Java, and Obj-C, so I grasp alot of concepts but sometimes certain functions like json and what not I'm not sure how to use just yet.  However I did the next best thing.  I ran the file that created said table.  Table was created.  Manually directed the browser to the exit.php file and it DID delete the file.  I'll update the question with new information that might be important for me to figure this out with help.

Comment: Salvador your awesome.  It was the directory path.  We have a security id that needs to be passed to access the page in the browser, wasn't thinking it would be needed with in the url for the java script though.  THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

quick reaction is that the sqlcommand is including a semi-colon, remove that

heres an alternate method, do this in your php code

html

```
  <input type="button" title="Click to close window" value="Close" 
   onclick="deleteTempTable('mytable');" style="width:80px" name="close">
```

exit.php

```
 if($_REQUEST['command'] == 'droptable') {  
echo dropTable($_REQUEST['tablename'] ));   
 }
 ...
 function dropTable($tableName){
 /*your sql stuff/code here*/
 $sqlCmd = 'Drop Table '.$tablename;
 $rz = odbc_exec($odbcConn, $sqlCmd);
      if (!$rz){
      $result = true;
      } else {
      $result = false;
      }
 return $result;
 }
```

then you could do this

```
function deleteTempTable(tablename) {
var params = 'command=droptable&tablename='+tablename;
$.ajax({
    url: "exit.php?"+params,
    success: function(data) {
        if(data == true) {
        alert("Deleting Temp Table");
        } else { 
          alert("Didnt work"); 
        }
    }
});
}
```

Just one way of doing it , i personally wouldnt use an onclick to fire the function, i prefer selector bound events

why are you storing this table name in session data? wouldnt a form var work out better?

Comment: I'm not really using a session variable, I'm using a company designed custom class to store the information.  I just threw that together to get the concept across of what I'm trying to accomplish.  The object works like a session and allows me to access the name across multiple reloads, and since it's already there I just decided to access it that way.  For the html to include the table name when calling the function I would have to change the template and pass it in when it reloads, which I guess wouldn't be a big deal, but seems a little messy.  The table name is randomly generated.

Comment: Though what I now know with some more testing is that the php isn't executing with the AJAX call.  I can run the php page separate from the ajax call it works as I would expect it too.